# apt-get install fuse - MAKEDEV not installed, skipping device node creation

Tags: debian, apt-get

This happened with command `apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade to debian jessie, after which I've tried to remove fuse, and install it again. Same error:

```
root@msgapp:/dev# apt-get install fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuse
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/69.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 191 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package fuse.
(Reading database ... 39354 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fuse_2.9.3-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fuse (2.9.3-10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up fuse (2.9.3-10) ...
MAKEDEV not installed, skipping device node creation.
device node not found
dpkg: error processing package fuse (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fuse
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**UPDATE**

Reinstalling makedev gives another problem:

```
root@msgapp:/dev# apt-get install makedev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  makedev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/42.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 129 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package makedev.
(Reading database ... 39347 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../makedev_2.3.1-93_all.deb ...
Unpacking makedev (2.3.1-93) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
ySetting up makedev (2.3.1-93) ...
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
```

There's [ticket](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=550334) raised, and their fix doesn't give any result:

```
root@msgapp:/dev#  cd /dev && ./MAKEDEV fuse
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
```

Comment: have you tried uninstalling, installing makedev, then reinstalling fuse? If that works, the problem is that this package depends on makedev, but that dependency is not in the package definition, and you should raise the ticket with Debian.

Comment: @AMADANONInc. updated question. there's ticket but their fix doesn't work

Comment: I wonder who's voted for offtopic?? unless this can be moved to serverfault.com this bug is till persist, what's wrong with debian community =( distupgrade is completely impossible with this bug.

Comment: Is this an OpenVZ VPS?

Answer (score 3):

This is more a comment than an answer, but I am not allowed to comment yet.

According to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1324257:
"Checking for udev and aborting the use of makedev if it is found is a normal thing."

Also https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2009/10/msg00434.html
"As I understand it, if udev is active, then invoking MAKEDEV is unnecessary. Therefore, this is not a warning but just a notification."

What happens to "apt-get install fuse" now that you have installed makedev?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, that this might be an issue using udev, makedev and fuse in an OpenVZ Virtual Private Server (VPS) container. I ran into the same issue when trying to upgrade a debian wheezy vps to a debian jessie vps. Maybe cantsay found a solution for this?

> "Is this an OpenVZ VPS?" – cantsay Feb 22 '16 at 0:16

Maybe, it's only to be solved by the ISP on the host of the vps.  https://virtuozzosupport.force.com/s/article/000017479

I guess this applies to OpenVZ too:
[debian bug #550334](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=550334)

> this bug basically causes the package to fail to install in any chroot
>   environment (including ltsp, pbuilder, and piuparts) where udev is installed,
>   as udev doesn't start (by default) when it detects a chroot environment.
>
> preferring udev over makedev (introduced in fuse-utils 2.8.1-1) causes this bug
>   to get triggered by default in chroots.

The solution to create the device node should not be like this

> root@msgapp:/dev#  cd /dev && ./MAKEDEV fuse

but rather like this

> root@msgapp:/dev#  cd /dev && MAKEDEV fuse

because MAKEDEV resides under /sbin/MAKEDEV and not /dev/MAKEDEV

As a workaround I deleted /dev/fuse to avoid /var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postinst to run udevadm info -q path -n /dev/fuse, which fails also on an existing special device

> crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 229 Jan 23 01:38 fuse.

Then I renamed /run/udev to /run/_udev, to bypass the dreaded complains of MAKEDEV

> /run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.

Finally I was able to install fuse either by `apt install fuse` or continue with `apt upgrade` and rename /run/_udev.

> mv /run/_udev /run/udev